# How to store a vector field for vtkUnstructuredGrid at the cell centroid

Tags: c++, vtk, paraview

Is it possible to store a vector field at the centroid of a tetrahedral mesh using `vtkStructuredGrid`? I tried the following code but VTK (version 8.1) complains about it, which I guess is due to the fact that this vector field is defined at the cell centroid.

```
Warning: In c:\vtk\src\common\datamodel\vtkdataset.cxx, line 443
vtkUnstructuredGrid (0000020A4EC10D50): Point array  with 3 components, has 137 tuples but there are only 64 points
```

The vector field is defined by:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> uGrid = vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid>::New();

// ... I already populated uGrid with points and tetrahedral information
// numberOfPoints = 64
// numberOfTetrahedra = 103

// Add a vector field at the centroid of each tetrahedral
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray> vectors = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray>::New();
vectors->SetNumberOfTuples(numberOfTetrahedra);
vectors->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
for (vtkIdType ielement = 0; ielement < numberOfTetrahedra; ielement++)
{
    vectors->InsertNextValue(vec[3 * ielement]);
    vectors->InsertNextValue(vec[3 * ielement + 1]);
    vectors->InsertNextValue(vec[3 * ielement + 2]);
}
uGrid->GetPointData()->SetVectors(vectors);

// Write the data to file
vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
writer->SetFileName("vtk_test_write_unstructured_grid.vtu");
writer->SetInputData(uGrid);
writer->Write();
```

- Does VTK provide any tools to save vectors at the centroid?
- Does VTK have a filter to map the cell-centered field to the points of the mesh?

I would appreciate for having any tips/suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data associated with cells you should use [vtkCellData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellData.html). So in your code try replacing the line where you set vector to

```
uGrid->GetCellData()->SetVectors(vectors);
```

These vectors are associated with the cell. You may interpret them as being associated with the cell centroid, although in the `.vtu` file you may not find any such explicit association with the centroids of the cells.

To map cell-centered fields to points of the mesh, consider exploring [vtkCellDataToPointData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellDataToPointData.html#details) class.

Comment: Thank you. Worked with no problem. A side question, for `vtkUnstructuredGrid`, what is the number of tuples for a 3D vector field defined at points of an unstructured mesh (#points = 100)? Should I set `myDoubleArrayVec->SetNumberOfTuples(100)` or `myDoubleArrayVec->SetNumberOfTuples(100*3)`? In both cases, `vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter` crashes when I try to write the unstructured mesh to a `.vtu` file and I have to comment out setting the number of tuples and use `InsertNextTypedTuple` instead of `setTuple3`. Do you know why is this?

Comment: Use `myDoubleArrayVec->SetNumberOfComponents(3)` and then you can use `myDoubleArrayVec->InsertNextTuple3(a, b, c)`.